# If and For statement doesn't seem to work

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I have a piece of code as below (I found out that it is where a problem of my full code lies in):

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, n As Integer, p As Integer
n = 0
p = 0
k = 0
MsgBox (ComboBox1.Value)
For i = 2 To 20
'MsgBox (Cells(i, 2))
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = ComboBox1.Value Then
        'k = i
        'n = n + 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
MsgBox (i)
```

I have a UserForm, in which I am sure that the ComboBox1.Value is selected before and there's obviously at least one cell whose value is equal to the ComboBox's value. The problem is that the "if... then" doesn't seem to work here, and the i variable still runs through its complete loop. There are no any alerts in VBA's Debug and I can't figure out why?[image]

Comment: That's like saying 2+2=5. The If statement cannot `not` work. You are saying value, what value? The values obviously aren't equal, period. Issues occur e.g. when comparing a number against a number as text, or the case is different or there are leading or trailing hidden characters or spaces or whatnot, issues with dates... etc. Now, what value can be found in both places?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sorry for the lack of clariry. I editted my post with the addition of two pictures (excel table and userform when running). Please help me check them. Many thanks!

Comment: One of it is a string or you have a format that hides decimals in the worksheet. The numbers in the worksheet are centered so we can't conclude anything, Try `If CStr(Cells(i, 2).Value) = ComboBox1.Value Then`, `If CStr(Cells(i, 2).Value) = CStr(ComboBox1.Value) Then` or even implement `Trim` with the latter. Also, you haven't qualified the range i.e. if the wrong worksheet is active who knows what is happening? Remember, each range has a worksheet and each worksheet has a workbook e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value`.